# vba - Add dict to dict

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a dictionary as an entry in another dict.

```
Dim jsonDictionary As New Dictionary

jsonDictionary(Cells(1, 1).Text) = Cells(1, 2).Text
Dim tempDict As New Dictionary
tempDict(Cells(2, 2).Text) = Cells(2, 3).Text
tempDict(Cells(3, 2).Text) = Cells(3, 3).Text
    
jsonDictionary(Cells(3, 1).Text) = tempDict
```

Last line throws an error.
Any idea?

Comment: `set jsonDictionary(Cells(3, 1).Text) = tempDict`

Comment: Way too easy... thanks.
Why do I have to use the "Set" here but not for the other assignments?

Comment: You must use `Set` when you're assigning an object. If it's a "simple" value then `Set` is not used.